# Can't use both Scrollview and Flatlist within same React Native component

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to use a Scrollview to scroll horizontally a mapped array and also a Flatlist to scroll vertically a list of items from another array but the combination of the 2 don't seem to work.

This is not a case on wrapping a Flatlist inside a Scrollview which causes a well known problem, I'm not getting the VirtualizedLists warning here.

Here's my code in the rendering section:

```
return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Scrollview style={styles.containerRow}>
        {selectedGenres.map((item) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                genreHandler(item.id, item.name);
              }}
              style={styles.containerRow}
              key={item.id}
            >
              <View style={styles.filterGenderLayout}>
                <Text style={styles.genderButton}>{item.name}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
      </Scrollview>
      <View style={styles.container}>               
        <View style={styles.containerRow}>
          <FlatList
            numColumns={3}
            data={result}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
            onEndReached={loadMoreCommit}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            renderItem={(itemData) => (
              <StarsItem
                id={itemData.item.id}
                poster={itemData.item.poster_path}
                title={itemData.item.title}
                onStarsSelection={fetchMovieHandler}
                showtitle={false}
              />
            )}
          />
        </View>        
      </View>
    </View>
```

As you can see the Scrollview and Flatlist are not nested but I get an error as invalid  element. If I use a normal View tag instead of Scrollview, everything looks fine except that I cannot scroll my first list horizontally.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

I tried to use Flatlist on both however I need the first to scroll horizontally and the second vertically with numColumns={3} meaning I get a different error.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? As I want to achieve the same thing.

Comment: yes, I replace the Scrollview with another independent FlatList. Basically now I have 2 FlatList contained in 2 different Views, the first with Horizontal option and the second with numColumns={3}. Works both on Android and iOs. Good luck @CarlBruiners

Comment: "Scrollview" should be "ScrollView".